# Universal app object distinct by variable

Tags: c#, linq, distinct, win-universal-app

I have a problem:

In my code I have this obj

```
//:extension for being saved locally
public class FOO 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string STRINGVALUE{ get; set; }
    public int INTVALUE { get; set; }
    //ecc..

    //SelectAll() method which returns all FOO in local DB
}
```

Now what I want is, in some cases, to pick all FOO obj where STRINGVALUE (or INTVALUE) is not duplicated.

For example:

```
List<FOO> fooes = new FOO().SelectAll();
List<FOO> uniqueIntFoo = fooes.distinct(); //here i have to set the clause
```

There is the Distinct() method in Linq, but it compare the entire item, not a single variable of it.

Any of you know how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about grouping the results, something like:
By both Int and StrValue:

```
var uniqueItems = fooes.GroupBy(x => new{x.IntVal, x.StrVal});
```

By IntVal:

```
var uniqueItems = fooes.GroupBy(x => x.IntVal);
```

Edit, as suggested by question's author:

```
fooes.GroupBy(x => x.INTVALUE).Select(y => y.First()).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: i succeded with fooes.GroupBy(x => x.INTVALUE).Select(y => y.First()).Distinct().ToList();        Your advice pointed me to the correct solution. probably also couse it was not perfectly explained. If you edit the answer with the code i wrote i will set it as the solution :)